# Google Sheets - need formula for three cells of 5 that match

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I need an excel-style formula for Google Sheets. I have five columns. I want to create a sixth column that contains a formula that examines the cells each row for the 5 columns. Each cell in each row of these five columns contain "yes" "no" and "conditional." I need a formula that says that if 3 of the 5 columns say "yes" or "conditional" then the new, sixth column with the formula says "approved". Thanks!

Comment: should *yes,yes,no,conditional* say approved ?? or do you need either three *yes* or three *conditional*

Comment: "yes, yes, no, conditional, no" would say "approved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel use this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:E1,"no")>2,"rejected",IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A1:E1,{"yes","conditional"}))>=3,"Approved",""))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

In Google Sheets It needs to be an array formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(COUNTIF(A1:E1,"no")>2,"rejected",IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A1:E1,{"yes","conditional"}))>=3,"Approved","")))
```

[image: ![![enter image description here]

The formula will mark as approved or rejected as soon as the criteria is met.  If 3 or more 'no's appear it will spit our rejected.  Or as soon as 3 of the others appear it will be marked as approved.

Comment: This is great & amazing! One more thing ---  how do I make it leave a blank cell in column F if there are some blank cells in columns A-E ?

Comment: If there are any blanks? If there is one blank, regardless of the other values, you want it to return blank? @MaryCatherine

Comment: And when you say blank, do you mean truly blank, as no formula and no value?  Or is there a formula that returns `""`?

Comment: This is great & amazing! I am using the Google Sheets Array Formula. One more thing --- Currently I have "Rejected" in after "approved" in the formula, where the "value if false" would be. This is a spreadsheet that gradually gets filled in by people, so there are often blank cells. If not all cells are full - for example, there are two yes, and three blank - it is automatically saying Rejected. Is there any way to add to this formula to put a condition to only say "Rejected" if there are two or more "No"s?

Comment: Sorry Scott, I was editing my comment before, posted too soon. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MaryCatherine see edit.  Remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer if it works for you.